# Difference between coefficient of Linear Regression and weights of SVR

Tags: svm

Difference between coefficients of Linear Regression and weights in Linear SVM?  Does they interpret same meaning. like impact of one variable on dependent variable keeping other variable constant.

Comment: SVM weights defines importance of a feature whereas coefficients in Linear Regression implies impact of the feature on dependent variable.